# How to install Ops Agent on Google Container Linux

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ops-agent, google-container-optimized-os

I am using Google Container Linux as an OS and want to get an alert when the disk is nearly full.

The issue is that it does not have an Ops Agent installed and does not report `bytes_used` to create an alert policy.

https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards/resourceList/gce_instance&timeDomain=1h&tab=inventory

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, [Ops agent is not yet supported](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent#supported_operating_systems) and the GCP Product team is working on it. However, there is no SLA, and there is already some discussions opened in [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ops-agent/issues/325).

checking the [Compute metrics list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-compute), It seems that in order to be able to use the metric `bytes_used` it is not necessary to install the agent, but you must enable the [COS Health monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/monitoring).

Please note that mentioned suggested metric is in Beta phase, which means:
"Beta: At beta, products or features are ready for broader customer testing and use. Betas are often publicly announced. There are no SLAs or technical support obligations in a beta release unless otherwise specified in product terms or the terms of a particular beta program."

After enabling the COS Health monitoring, you can create an alerting policy by referring to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui#default).

Comment: Thanks. Does the "node problem detector" logging agent report all mounted disks, or just the boot disk? I want an alert on one of the mounted disks, is this possible?

Comment: mounted disks are also included on the reporting